# Can we say "it's said to have been..."

Tags: present-perfect

One wrote

> I've heard about this thing this morning and I don't know anything more than a Polish trucker is said to be killed in Germany.

I changed it into

> I've heard about this thing this morning and I don't know anything more than **this that** a Polish trucker is said to **have been killed** in Germany.

Is *this that* required?

What is the grammar for "said to have been killed"? Is it different from the original phrase?

Comment: Both ***this*** and ***that*** are (independently) optional. If you're going to include ***this*** you'll need to follow it with a detectable *pause* regardless of whether you include ***that*** or not, but if you *don't* include it there's no reason to pause anywhere after *...and I don't know*. And it must always be ***said to have been killed*** - your first version is never idiomatic.

Comment: It is said **to be** an acquired taste.  It is said **to have been thought** the nectar of the gods.  The tense depends on the context.

Comment: They are also jointly optional. ...I don't know anything more than a trucker is said to have been killed... ... I don't know anything more than (what) he told me... I don't know anything more than I was told.

Answer (score 1):

"Said to have been killed" is correct in this context, but if you use "this that" there should be some punctuation after "this", either a long dash or a colon.

> I don't know anything more than this -- that a Polish trucker ...
>
> I don't know anything more than this: that a Polish trucker ...

Also the "that" is not necessary:

> I don't know anything more than this: a Polish trucker is said to have been killed in Germany.

Comment: Alternately, I think a more natural phrasing would be to leave out *this* entirely: "I don't know anything more **than that** a Polish trucker..."

Comment: @stangdon  *This* followed by a long dash is dramatic, and some people -- myself included -- tend to write this way (even if we shouldn't).  I agree it's less common but I wouldn't say it's less *natural*.

Comment: Well, maybe *natural* was a bit strong, but I think phrasings like "than this -- that a..." are rather explicitly dramatic.  In common speech, I think people are more likely to say "than that a", no?

Comment: Sure, especially in this context.

Comment: A comma would work there just as well.

Comment: @Andrew why said to be is wrong here?

Comment: @confusedguy  "killed" represents an event, not a condition.  It happened in the past so you can't use the present tense infinitive.  You could say, *"He is said **to be** dead"* because that is a current condition.